# VS: Unit test in the same project

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, projects-and-solutions, sharpdevelop

I have inherited a C# project with NUnit tests that reside in the same project as the tested code. When importing these in VS 2015, they are not runnable via the test running mechanism (test explorer is empty). The project itself can be built and runs fine.

Since the tests are properly runnable in SharpDevelop and out of respect for the maintainer, I'd like to avoid changing the project structure, but I'd like to know how to configure VS so that these tests appear and are runnable.

Comment: Have you added the NUnit Test Runner to your project so that the Visual Studio Test Runner can detect the NUnit projects? https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/

Comment: Above link is good for NUnit version 2. Just in case you are using NUnit 3, the link is nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter.